# Prove that $nS_{tt}(\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2)\geq \sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2$

Tags: statistics, inequality

Let $c_1,\cdots, c_n,t_1,\cdots,t_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nc_it_i=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i=1$. Suppose that there're $i,j$ such that $t_i\neq t_j$. Prove that $nS_{tt}(\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2)\geq \sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2$ with $S_{tt}:=\sum_{i=1}^n(t_i-\overline t)^2$ and $\overline t:=(\sum_{i=1}^nt_i)/n$.

---

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2=S_{tt}+n(\overline t)^2$ and I tried to use Cauchy-Schwartz to prove that inequality, however I failed. Please help me to prove that inequality

---

**EDIT:**

That inequality is related to the fact that among the unbiased linear estimators of $\alpha$ in simple regression analysis the least square estimator $\hat\alpha$ is the one of minimum variance.So that inequality is expected to attain its minimum when $c_i=\frac{S_{tt}-n\overline t(t_i-\overline t)}{nS_{tt}}$ for all $i=1,\cdots,n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the two rv $(X,Y)$ on the probability space $\Omega=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with the following definition $$(X_i=t_i, Y_i=nc_i)$$ $\Omega$ is equiped with the uniform distribution. As a consequence for any $f$ we have
$$E(f(X,Y))=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i,nc_i).$$

Hypotheses $\sum_{i}c_it_i=0$ and $\sum_{i}c_i=1$ mean $E(XY)=0$ and $E(Y)=1.$ Dividing the desired inequality by $n^3$ shows that it is equivalent to
$$\sigma^2(X)E(Y^2)\geq E(X^2)=\sigma^2(X)+E(X)^2$$ which can be rewritten since $E(Y)=1$ as $$\sigma^2(X)\sigma^2(Y)\geq E(X)^2.$$ Finally denoting $A=X-E(X)$ and $B=Y-1$ and using $E(XY)=0$ and $E(Y)=1$ we get that $E(AB)=-E(X).$ We are now in position to apply the Schwarz inequality to $(A,B)$ and prove the result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I want to confirm something: basically you're using the uniform probability in the set $\Omega:=\{(t_1,nc_1),\cdots,(t_n,nc_n)\}$ and you're also assuming that $|\Omega|=n$. However I'm not assuming that all those constants are different!

Comment: I think that in fact your solution only works if we assume that $\Omega$ has $n$ elements. But this isn't true in the general case!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear. What I said was that I think your proof doesn't work if, for instance, $t_1=t_2$ and $c_1=c_2$. I think that your proof only works we assume that $\{(t_1,nc_1),\cdots,(t_n,nc_n)\}$ has $n$ elements.

Comment: So, the 'general case ' is when {t_i,c_i}'s are not distinct? No problem, $\Omega=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.....

Comment: This don't solve the problem. You are assuming that there're a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and random variables $X,Y$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X=t_i,Y=nc_i)=1/n$ for all $i$. However this isn't true if $\{(t_1,nc_1),\cdots,(t_n,nc_n)\}$ doesn't have $n$ elements.

Comment: You are correct. I should say that $i$ is uniformly distributed on $\Omega.$ Define the pair $(X_i,Y_i)_{i\in \Omega}$ by $(X_i,Y_i)=(t_i,nc_i).$ Then for any function $f$ we have$$E(f(X,Y))=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i,nc_i).$$ I am correcting above. Defining the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is not necessary, and could be done as follows : given  $(t,nc)$ define $m(t,nc)$ as the number of $i$ such that $(t,nc)=(t_i,nc_i)$ leading to $\Pr(X=t,Y=nc)=m(t,nc)/n.$

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct. I posted an answer defining exactly the sample space $\Omega$ and the random variables $X,Y$.

Answer (score 0):

The Gérard Letac's answer is indeed correct. But since it took me a while to understand it, I'll try to explain the details below.

Suppose that $(t_{k_1},nc_{k_1}),\cdots, (t_{k_m},nc_{k_m})$ are all the distinct pairs that show in $(t_1,nc_1),\cdots, (t_n,nc_n)$ with $k_i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ for all $i\in \{1,\cdots,m\}$. Suppose also that $(t_{k_i},nc_{k_i})$ appears $m_i$ times for all $i\in \{1,\cdots,m\}$.

Then $\Sigma _{i=1}^mm_i=n\,\,\color{red}{(1)}$, $\Sigma _{i=1}^mm_it_{k_i}=\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_i\,\,\color{red}{(2)}$, $\Sigma _{i=1}^mm_it_{k_i}^2=\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_i^2\,\,\color{red}{(3)}$, $\Sigma _{i=1}^mm_ic_{k_i}=\Sigma _{i=1}^nc_i=1\,\,\color{red}{(4)}$, $\Sigma _{i=1}^mm_ic_{k_i}^2=\Sigma _{i=1}^nc_i^2\,\,\color{red}{(5)}$, and $\Sigma _{i=1}^mm_it_{k_i}c_{k_i}=\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_ic_i=0\,\,\color{red}{(6)}$.

Define $\Omega:=\big\{(t_{k_1},nc_{k_1}),\cdots, (t_{k_m},nc_{k_m})\big\}$.

Consider the probability $\mathbb{P}:2^\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\mathbb{P}((t_{k_i},nc_{k_i}))=m_i/n$ for all $i\in \{1,\cdots,m\}$. Such probability exists because of $(1)$.

It's easy to prove, using $(2),\cdots,(6)$, that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\overline t$, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=(\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_i^2)/n$, $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\Sigma _{i=1}^nc_i=1$, $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=n(\Sigma _{i=1}^nc_i^2)$, and $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_ic_i=0$.

Therefore $\text{Var}(X)=(\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_i^2)/n-(\overline t)^2=[(\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_i^2)-n(\overline t)^2]/n=S_{tt}/n$, $\text{Var}(Y)=n(\Sigma _{i=1}^nc_i^2)-1$, and $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=-\overline t$.

Knowing that $\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)\geq (\text{Cov}(X,Y))^2$, we obtain

$$(S_{tt}/n)(n\Sigma _{i=1}^nc_i^2-1)\geq (\overline t)^2 $$

which implies that $nS_{tt}(\Sigma _{i=1}^nc_i^2)\geq S_{tt}+n(\overline t)^2=\Sigma _{i=1}^nt_i^2$.$\square$